# cannot build when ngx-daterangepicker added

Tags: angular, ngx-daterangepicker-material

when iam adding ngx date rangepicker module to my angular project,cannot build it. it failed with error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/fesm5/ngx-daterangepicker-material.js
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

anybody know what is the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have the answer... this issue is with the new version of ngx-daterangepicker release. When I used a lower version, I could build with no issues. Thank you for your support.

Version -

```
"ngx-daterangepicker-material": "~2.0.2"
```

Comment: can you please mention the version which you were used, facing the same issue.

Comment: try  with "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "~2.0.2",

Comment: got fixed this issue with the 2.1.11 version.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-daterangepicker-material-build-problem

This is working while using `ng serve` but
I build the entire angular app using `ng build --prod` and the issue was the following

```
"fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

and as the stackblitz exports doesn't contian environments directory you should resolve the issue either by adding such files or comment this lines on `angular.json`

second problem was for old version of angular dependencies which stackblitz offers, so I updated them on `packages.json` to what `ng new myApp` generates.

```
"@angular/animations": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/common": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/core": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/router": "~9.0.1",

"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
"@angular/cli": "~9.0.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.1",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.0.1",

"typescript": "~3.7.5"
```

finally it successfully build using `ng build --prod`

Comment: sorry bro i cannot update to this version(9.0) other componenents will have issues

Comment: try changing/updating `@angular-devkit/build-angular` package. it seems there might be something went wrong.

Comment: Package "ngx-datepicker-material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" (extended), would install "9.0.2"). how to fix it ??.can u help?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed a very similar kind of problem I fixed by upgrading to

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.23",
```